# Understanding "Inequality preserved by dropping 1 in numerator"

Tags: inequality, induction

I'm looking at [a solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GE0o2.jpg) to a problem on estimating the sum of inverse squares by induction.  In the solution, it states: \begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{k+1}{\frac{1}{j^2}}&=\sum_{j=0}^k{\frac{1}{j^2}}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\leq2-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \\
&\leq2-\frac{(k+1)^2-k^2}{k(k+1)^2}\leq2-\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)^2} \\
&\leq2-\frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}=2-\frac{1}{k+1}
\end{align*}  The first line is annotated with "assumption!", the second "inequality preserved by dropping 1 in numerator", and the third has a checkmark.

What does the annotation on the second line mean? And how does it preserve the inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially the step of concern is moving from

$$2 - \frac{k^2 + k +1}{k(k+1)^2} \le 2 - \frac{k(k+1)}{k(k+1)^2}$$

In particular we're concerned about the numerators. Notice that

$$k^2 + k + 1 \ge k^2 + k = k(k+1)$$

Multiply throughout by $-1$ to get

$$-k(k+1) \le - \Big( k^2 + k + 1 \Big)$$

Divide both sides by $k(k+1)^2$ (which doesn't change the direction of the inequality, since it is not negative) and then add on $2$ to both sides to complete the justification.

---

More simply, by subtracting $1$ from the numerator of the left-hand side (i.e. adding $1/(k(k+1)^2)$, due to the negative out front), you get something bigger, and nice to factor.